# Is scikit's Linear Discriminant Analysis and Fisher Discriminant Analysis the same method?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I would like to know if the [LDA method implemented in scikit's package](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/lda_qda.html#lda-qda) for Python is the same as Fisher Linear Discriminant method.

From what i saw i guess so ...

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

FDA is LDA from the practical point of view, the actual difference comes from theory that lead to the classifier's rule, as LDA assumes Gaussian distributions and Fisher's idea was to analyze the ratio of inner/outer class variances.

@badc0re answer incorrectly "merges" Fisher's Discriminant Analysis (FDA) and Kernel FIsher Discriminant (KDA), which has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @Ins make sure you have the newest version of sklearn, up until recently there was a scaling issue with the algorithm which, although it lead to perfect discrimination of classes, didn't lead to the commonly expected mapping when `transform` was applied.

Comment: @eickenberg my scikit's version is 0.15.2 ... Is there any problem with this version? Is it necessary to use transform? The only things i am doing is (the || is only to separate the code lines):


clf = LDA() ||
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=10) ||
print("[LDA]Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std()))

Comment: accuracy should not be affected. You don't need transform unless you explicitly want to do e.g. what is done [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_pca_vs_lda.html#example-decomposition-plot-pca-vs-lda-py)

Comment: @lejlot do you know of any papers/resources that discuss this relationship? I.e. how Fisher's representation relates to the LDA representation? Thanks